# Is it possible to split multipolygon into smaller polygons?

Tags: polygons, geotools

i have a multipolygon geometry like this:
[image: Gray area is the area where is no rivers, roads, villages and etc.]

I need somehow to split this geometry to smaller polygons, to gray ones. So, i would like to ask if it is possible and how i could do that. Thanks.

Comment: What is your implementation/framework you are using to display/handle you ploygons?

Comment: I am using geotools's Map viewer

Comment: And the polygons are coming from which type of datasource?

Comment: Geometry in the picture is a result of two layers symmetrical difference. Therefore, it is a single geometry object. Although, i think @Brett Walker's answer should be what i needed. I am going to check his suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending upon the implementation you are using, a multi-polygon is a collection of polygons. If you can obtain a list of the polygons comprising the multi-polygon via you implementation's API then you are a large way to doing what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried casting geometry to MultiPolygon type and then i was able to retrieve list of polygons.